# Convert Geodetic Cordinates to Lambert Conformal Conic

Tags: c#, geospatial, wgs84

I have an FAA sectional map from [here](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/VFR/chartlist_sect).  Each package includes a .tif of the chart in question, a .htm file describing the chart, and a .tfw world file. The map projection is a Lambert conformal conic projection.

I'm working on a C# app that needs to be able to convert normal WGS84 (lat/lon) coordinates to (x,y) positions (pixel) on the map.

**Things I know about the map:**

The Spatial_Reference_Information section from the HTML that came with the map says that it is a Lambert conformal conic projection, and uses WGS83.  The Lambert conic parameters are:

```
Standard_Parallel: 46.666670
Standard_Parallel: 41.333330
Longitude_of_Central_Meridian: -120.995830
Latitude_of_Projection_Origin: 46.750000
```

And I the world file for the map looks like this:

```
63.5278030000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-63.5278030000
-411036.1271487368
261242.9877766267
```

What's the simplest way to convert my geodetic coordinates into Cartesian coordinates for my map?

C# code/examples preferred, but C++/Java/others are okay too.  It's the algorithm I need, not the code.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Im about to begin work on a similar project. Do you know if any more recent c# tools worth investigating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several libraries for coordinate conversions.

You can see these: [GeoUtility](http://geoutility.codeplex.com/), [Proj.Net](http://projnet.codeplex.com/), [GeoTools](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=geotools&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.geotools.org/&ei=CnW5UpbfAcKJrQen04GQCg&usg=AFQjCNELU-QmeB98qUR3g_ZRjZRoAcCYsQ&sig2=fSuPnw85exXJ2NT_wtEL5w) and [GeoTools Example](http://ariasprado.name/2012/08/13/quick-and-dirty-coordinate-transforming-using-geotools.html) And ...